# Missing $ inserted. \end{align}

Tags: equations

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{physics}

\begin{align}
    \Gamma_\textbf{P}(\textbf{r})=-\frac{2\pi}{m}\int \frac{\dd[3]{k}}{(2\pi)^3} e^{-i\textbf{k\vdot\textbf{r}}}f_p(\textbf{k})
    \end{align}

\nocite{}
\bibliographystyle{}
\bibliography{hafiz}
\end{document}
```

The output is fine but giving lot of same error message. Please help

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: %\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{physics} I have used these

Comment: please edit the question, do not post it in the comments

Answer (score 3):

Your problem arises from the misuse of `\textbf` in the first subscript: as @Zarko pointed out, for it to work, instead of `\Gamma_\textbf{P}` you could use `\Gamma_{\textbf{P}}`. **Nevertheless this is not recommended, since** `textbf` **is a text command.** In order to have bold text in math mode you'd better use:

- `mathbf` which uses an upright bold math font, or
- `\usepackage{bm}` and then the `bm` command, which gives an italic bold math font
- mix and match the two.

Also, is quite pointless to have an `align` environment without alignments. I substituted it with a plain equation.

Example with `mathbf`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage{amssymb} 
 \usepackage{makeidx} 
 \usepackage{graphicx} 
 \usepackage{physics} 
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\Gamma_\mathbf{P}(\mathbf{r})=-\frac{2\pi}{m}\int \frac{\dd[3]{k}}{(2\pi)^3} e^{-i\mathbf{k\cdot\mathbf{r}}}f_p(\mathbf{k})
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Example with `bm`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage{amssymb} 
 \usepackage{makeidx} 
 \usepackage{graphicx} 
 \usepackage{physics} 
 \usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\Gamma_{\bm{P}}(\bm{r})=-\frac{2\pi}{m}\int \frac{\dd[3]{k}}{(2\pi)^3} e^{-i\bm{k\cdot\bm{r}}}f_p(\bm{k})
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I disagree.  Problem is error in writing of sub script with `\textbf{...}` . Instead of `\Gamma_\textbf{P}` should be `\Gamma_{\textbf{P}}` . However, use of `\textbf{...}` in maths expresion is not right way. It should be replaced - as you mentioned in answer -- by `mathbf`, etc.

Comment: @Zarko I'll correct the answer right away

Answer (score 2):

You don't want `\textbf` for vectors, but `\vec`. “Wait!” you'll say, “I don't want vectors with an arrow above their head!”

Don't worry! Neither do I!

What I mean is that you should use a semantic command for your objects and `\vec` is a good choice.

The main problem in your code is `\textbf{v\vdot\textbf{r}}`: `\textbf` starts text mode, and `\vdot` is only valid in math mode. Anyway, also

```
\mathbf{v\vdot\mathbf{r}}
```

is wrong and should be `\mathbf{v}\vdot\mathbf{r}`. Better yet, use `\vec` (or other semantic command named as you prefer) like below.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}% for the second choice
\usepackage{physics}

\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
%\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\bm{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\Gamma_{\vec{P}}(\vec{r})=
-\frac{2\pi}{m}\int\frac{\dd[3]{k}}{(2\pi)^3} e^{-i\vec{k}\vdot\vec{r}}f_p(\vec{k})
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

By the way, a subscript should be braced, if it doesn't consist in a *single* letter or number (but bracing also these doesn't harm). Also `align` should not be used for single displayed equations.

[image]

Should you change your mind and decide that bold italic for vectors is better, just switch the comment sign `%` and enable

```
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\bm{#1}}
```

to get, upon rerunning LaTeX,

[image]

Comment: Nice explanation!